# Probability Puzzle : Robot and coins

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence, puzzle

Someone walks into your room and dumps a huge bag of quarters all over the floor. They spread them out so no quarters are on top of any other quarters. a robot then comes into the room and is programmed such that if it sees a head, it flips it to tails. If it sees a tail, it throws it in the air. the robot moves around randomly forever. Will there be a convergence in distribution of heads vs. tails?

I am trying this puzzle for the past two days . But got lot of confusions !! As i don't know what is convergence in probability,i cannot proceed further. Please don't provide a link to wikipedia for convergence in probability.Can someone give me a simple definition of convergence in probability and explain the solution to the puzzle ?

Comment: Throws in air in the sense,it tosses the coin and there is 50% for head and 50% tail.To understand this,it took a while for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will reach an equilibrium of 2/3 tails and 1/3 heads.  At that point, the expected outcome of the next iteration is:

- 1/3 of the coins, which were previously heads, will all be flipped to tails.
- 1/3 of the coins, which were previously tails, will be tossed and land heads-up.
- 1/3 of the coins, which were previously tails, will be tossed and land tails-up.

giving 2/3 tails and 1/3 heads again.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Let $h$ be the proportion of heads among the coins and $t=1-h$ the proportion of tails.  In a stationary state, the chance of a transition heads$ \to $ tails must equal the chance of a transition tails$ \to $heads  So we have $h=\frac t2$ and the equilibrium state is  $\frac 13$ heads and $\frac 23$ tails.

Comment: Sir,thanks for your answer.But i am not very good at probability,can you elaborate the answer so that every reader like me can understand.

Comment: If the robot find a heads coin (probability $h$) it goes to tails.  If it finds a tails coin it only goes to heads with probability $\frac 12$

Comment: We don't know the dynamics is Markovian for multiple coins, and if it is, the answer can differ from 2/3 due to robot getting trapped on a subset of states.  I posted another answer to try and state what is true in complete generality and without any assumption on the dynamics.

Comment: So will there be a convergence ? I got confused after zyx answer :)

Comment: Yes, there will be convergence with probability $1$ as long as the coins are chosen at random.  zyx was talking about cases where the coins to examine are not chosen randomly, in particular where some coins are only checked finitely many times.

Comment: Thanks sir !! By the way,can you explain how to calculate equilibrium state ? I still don't understand how can that converge when the robot flips the coin randomly ? Can you explain in simple terms ? Please !!

Comment: The idea is that (as I said) the chance of changing a head to a tail must equal the chance of changing a tail to a head.  If $h$ is the proportion of heads, the chance of head to tail is $h$, because that is the chance the next coin starts out heads.  The chance of tails to heads is $\frac 12(1-h)$ because you have to find a tail (probability $1-h$) and then have it come down heads (probability $\frac 12$).  You set those equal and solve for $h$ to get the equilibrium.

Comment: I was not talking about "cases where coins are not chosen randomly".  It is possible for coins to be chosen randomly by the robot (for example, uniformly from the coins it can see nearby) and still get trapped on a subset due to the arrangement of coins, topology of the room or other factors.  A common, and fairly general, model of this kind of problem would be to have Markovian dynamics and in Markov chain models there arises the issue of whether the equilibrium distribution gives nonzero probability to all states.  It might require non-local moves by the robot to escape this possibility.

Comment: Convergence with probability 1, to some limiting average, is true independent of whether any randomness is involved, but dependent on a proper definition of what "converge" means for this problem.  If the robot moves nonrandomly, you don't need the "with probability 1" qualifier; the distribution will settle into an infinite loop that revisits each state in the loop equally often, and this is convergent when averaged.

Answer (score 4):

> Will there be a convergence in distribution of heads vs. tails?

Yes, but *not* necessarily to $2/3$ tails and $1/3$ heads.

The visible distribution of heads and tails fluctuates, and does not converge.

The average of the distributions after the first $n$ moves by the robot converges (with probability $1$ and for large $n$) to a limiting distribution.

The limiting distribution for one coin that is moved infinitely often by the robot, is $2/3$ Tails and $1/3$ Heads.  This is the equilibrium distribution of the two state Markov chain that describes the robot operating forever on one coin.

The limiting distribution for the subset of coins that are moved infinitely often is $2/3$ T, $1/3$ H.

The limiting distribution for all the coins exists, but it can differ from $(2/3,1/3)$ if there is a positive probability for at least one coin to be visited only a finite number of times.  Whether that probability is positive depends on the programming of the robot and other factors.

Comment: I think we should take "the robot moves around randomly" to say it randomly selects the next coin with uniform probability.  In that case it cannot get stuck.

Comment: The purpose of this answer was to identify what is rigorously true in complete generality, without any assumption about how the robot operates, and with clarity about what "convergence" can mean in this puzzle. The analysis leading to the answer revealed two hidden issues. One is that the robot can spoil other modes of convergence, or change the limiting distribution, by adding delays after some actions.  The other is that the answer can change if the robot can get stuck.  It seemed more illuminating to bring that to the fore than to silently preclude it with a simplifying assumption.

Answer (score 2):

The solution to the above problem can be simply understood in terms of Markov chain theory. Let $1,0$ denote Heads, Tails respectively.

$X_n \in \{0,1\}$ be a random variable describing the no. of heads (1) and tails (0) at $n^{th}$ instant.

Then the transition probability matrix for this Markov chain is
$$ 
\mathcal{P}= \begin{bmatrix}
1/2 & 1/2 \\
1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Thus $[P(X_{n+1}=0) \ \ \ \ P(X_{n+1}=1)]= [P(X_{n}=0) \ \ \ \ P(X_{n}=1)] \mathcal{P}$

Limiting distribution is same as the stationary distribution is equivalent to solving for the left eigenvector of $\mathcal{P}$, i.e
$$
\bar{x}=\bar{x} \mathcal{P}
$$
which yields $[2/3 \ \ \ 1/3]$ as the required answer.